# bitnami Keycloak docker is not starting- "Failed to delete PingData in database"

Tags: docker-compose, keycloak, bitnami

My docker compose has the following 2 services and keycloak used to startup just fine until today:

```
postgresql:
  image: 'docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:11'
  environment:
    - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    - POSTGRESQL_USERNAME=bn_keycloak
    - POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=bitnami_keycloak
    - KEYCLOAK_ENABLE_STATISTICS=true
  volumes:
    - 'postgresql_data:/bitnami/postgresql'

keycloak-1:
  image: docker.io/bitnami/keycloak:latest
  ports:
    - '80:8080'
    - '8443:8443'
  environment:
    - KEYCLOAK_CREATE_ADMIN_USER=true
    - KEYCLOAK_JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_PROTOCOL=JDBC_PING
    - 'KEYCLOAK_JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_PROPERTIES=datasource_jndi_name=>java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS, initialize_sql=>"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS JGROUPSPING ( own_addr varchar(200) NOT NULL, cluster_name varchar(200) NOT NULL, created timestamp default current_timestamp, ping_data BYTEA, constraint PK_JGROUPSPING PRIMARY KEY (own_addr, cluster_name))"'
  depends_on:
    - postgresql
```

When I start the container, all of a sudden today, I get lots of ServerService Thread Pool errors:

```
WARNING: Native build is an experimental feature and could change at any time
base_postgresql_1 is up-to-date
Recreating base_keycloak-1_1 ... done
Attaching to base_keycloak-1_1
keycloak-1_1       | keycloak 22:33:45.49 
keycloak-1_1       | keycloak 22:33:45.49 Welcome to the Bitnami keycloak container
keycloak-1_1       | keycloak 22:33:45.49 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-keycloak
keycloak-1_1       | keycloak 22:33:45.49 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-keycloak/issues
keycloak-1_1       | keycloak 22:33:45.49 
keycloak-1_1       | keycloak 22:33:45.49 INFO  ==> ** Starting keycloak setup **
keycloak-1_1       | keycloak 22:33:45.50 INFO  ==> Validating settings in KEYCLOAK_* env vars...
keycloak-1_1       | keycloak 22:33:45.50 INFO  ==> Trying to connect to PostgreSQL server postgresql...
keycloak-1_1       | keycloak 22:33:45.51 INFO  ==> Found PostgreSQL server listening at postgresql:5432
keycloak-1_1       | keycloak 22:33:45.51 INFO  ==> Configuring database settings
keycloak-1_1       | keycloak 22:33:49.30 INFO  ==> Configuring jgroups settings
keycloak-1_1       | keycloak 22:33:51.97 INFO  ==> Configuring cache count
keycloak-1_1       | keycloak 22:33:54.57 INFO  ==> Configuring authentication cache count
keycloak-1_1       | keycloak 22:33:57.83 INFO  ==> Configuring log level
keycloak-1_1       | keycloak 22:34:00.41 INFO  ==> Configuring proxy address forwarding
keycloak-1_1       | keycloak 22:34:03.36 INFO  ==> Configuring node identifier
keycloak-1_1       | 
keycloak-1_1       | keycloak 22:34:06.34 INFO  ==> ** keycloak setup finished! **
keycloak-1_1       | keycloak 22:34:06.35 INFO  ==> ** Starting keycloak **
keycloak-1_1       | =========================================================================
keycloak-1_1       | 
keycloak-1_1       |   JBoss Bootstrap Environment
keycloak-1_1       | 
keycloak-1_1       |   JBOSS_HOME: /opt/bitnami/keycloak
keycloak-1_1       | 
keycloak-1_1       |   JAVA: /opt/bitnami/java/bin/java
keycloak-1_1       | 
keycloak-1_1       |   JAVA_OPTS:  -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman     -Djava.awt.headless=true  --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED
keycloak-1_1       | 
keycloak-1_1       | =========================================================================
keycloak-1_1       | 
keycloak-1_1       | 22:34:07,041 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.11.0.Final
keycloak-1_1       | 22:34:07,407 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.4.12.Final
keycloak-1_1       | 22:34:07,415 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 2.4.0.Final
keycloak-1_1       | 22:34:07,521 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0049: Keycloak 15.0.2 (WildFly Core 15.0.1.Final) starting
keycloak-1_1       | 22:34:08,114 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.15.3.Final
keycloak-1_1       | 22:34:08,383 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 6) WFLYCTL0033: Extension 'security' is deprecated and may not be supported in future     versions
keycloak-1_1       | 22:34:08,601 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the     deprecation.
keycloak-1_1       | 22:34:08,645 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 9) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description     operation to learn more about the deprecation.
keycloak-1_1       | 22:34:08,715 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) WFLYDR0001: Content added at location /opt/bitnami/keycloak/standalone/data/content/c5/    5fa6c6a460550cd8d70e55c435ef6834bff971/content
keycloak-1_1       | 22:34:08,832 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
keycloak-1_1       | 22:34:08,857 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-7) XNIO version 3.8.4.Final
keycloak-1_1       | 22:34:08,866 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-7) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.8.4.Final
keycloak-1_1       | 22:34:08,904 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
keycloak-1_1       | 22:34:08,916 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
keycloak-1_1       | 22:34:08,934 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0009: Starting Jakarta Connectors Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.4.27.Final)
keycloak-1_1       | 22:34:08,934 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.jgroups] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 43) WFLYCLJG0001: Activating JGroups subsystem. JGroups version 4.2.11
keycloak-1_1       | 22:34:08,939 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.health] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) WFLYHEALTH0001: Activating Base Health Subsystem
keycloak-1_1       | 22:34:08,941 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 41) WFLYRS0016: RESTEasy version 3.15.1.Final
keycloak-1_1       | 22:34:08,946 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
keycloak-1_1       | 22:34:08,949 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=5.0.3.Final-redhat-00007
keycloak-1_1       | 22:34:08,955 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 40) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 24 IO threads with 192 max task threads based on     your 12 available processors
keycloak-1_1       | 22:34:08,962 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBoss Remoting version 5.0.20.Final
keycloak-1_1       | 22:34:08,958 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.metrics] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) WFLYMETRICS0001: Activating Base Metrics Subsystem
keycloak-1_1       | 22:34:08,995 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 2.2.5.Final starting
keycloak-1_1       | 22:34:08,996 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.4)
keycloak-1_1       | 22:34:09,010 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
keycloak-1_1       | 22:34:09,019 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
keycloak-1_1       | 22:34:09,032 WARN  [org.wildfly.clustering.web.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) WFLYCLWEBUT0007: No routing provider found for default-server; using legacy provider based     on static configuration
keycloak-1_1       | 22:34:09,041 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
keycloak-1_1       | 22:34:09,078 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (    version 42.2)
keycloak-1_1       | 22:34:09,090 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = postgresql
keycloak-1_1       | 22:34:09,139 WARN  [org.wildfly.extension.elytron] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYELY00023: KeyStore file '/opt/bitnami/keycloak/standalone/configuration/application.keystore' does not     exist. Used blank.
keycloak-1_1       | 22:34:09,177 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path '/opt/bitnami/keycloak/welcome-content' with options [    directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
keycloak-1_1       | 22:34:09,198 WARN  [org.wildfly.extension.elytron] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYELY01084: KeyStore /opt/bitnami/keycloak/standalone/configuration/application.keystore not found, it     will be auto generated on first use with a self-signed certificate for host localhost
keycloak-1_1       | WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
keycloak-1_1       | WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.wildfly.extension.elytron.SSLDefinitions (jar:file:/opt/bitnami/keycloak/modules/system/layers/base/org/wildfly/extension/elytron/main/    wildfly-elytron-integration-15.0.1.Final.jar!/) to method com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider.isFIPS()
keycloak-1_1       | WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.wildfly.extension.elytron.SSLDefinitions
keycloak-1_1       | WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
keycloak-1_1       | WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

... until finally I see this:

```
    keycloak-1_1       | 22:39:09,543 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0348: Timeout after [300] seconds waiting for service container stability. Operation     will roll back. Step that first updated the service container was 'add' at address '[
keycloak-1_1       |     ("core-service" => "management"),
keycloak-1_1       |     ("management-interface" => "http-interface")
keycloak-1_1       | ]'
keycloak-1_1       | 22:39:09,566 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment keycloak-server.war (runtime-name: keycloak-server.war) in 17ms
keycloak-1_1       | 22:39:09,567 INFO  [org.keycloak.subsystem.server.extension.KeycloakProviderDeploymentProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-4) Undeploying Keycloak provider: keycloak-metrics-spi-2.4.0.jar
keycloak-1_1       | 22:39:09,574 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment keycloak-metrics-spi-2.4.0.jar (runtime-name:     keycloak-metrics-spi-2.4.0.jar) in 24ms
keycloak-1_1       | 22:39:09,575 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0008: Undertow HTTPS listener https suspending
keycloak-1_1       | 22:39:09,581 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0007: Undertow HTTPS listener https stopped, was bound to 0.0.0.0:8443
keycloak-1_1       | 22:39:10,736 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) 686f5f3e69c1: JOIN(686f5f3e69c1) sent to e4a802d5ef7c timed out (after 3000 ms), on try 7
keycloak-1_1       | 22:39:14,213 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) 686f5f3e69c1: JOIN(686f5f3e69c1) sent to 01fadbd6831b timed out (after 3000 ms), on try 7
```

[snip]
and a bunch more:

```
keycloak-1_1       | 22:39:14,587 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$ModelControllerServiceInitializationBootStepHandler$1@25e2ac57 for operation boottime-controller-initializer-step at address [] failed --     java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.waitForRemovals(OperationContextImpl.java:525)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.handleResult(AbstractOperationContext.java:1559)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:1513)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1496)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.access$400(AbstractOperationContext.java:1360)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeResultHandlerPhase(AbstractOperationContext.java:912)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:762)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:468)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1415)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:529)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:515)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:477)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.server@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:459)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.server@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:412)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:416)
keycloak-1_1       |    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
keycloak-1_1       | 
keycloak-1_1       | 22:39:14,589 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.client] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$ModelControllerServiceInitializationBootStepHandler$1@25e2ac57 for operation boottime-controller-initializer-step at address [] failed --     java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
keycloak-1_1       | 22:39:14,590 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0022: Deploy of deployment "keycloak-metrics-spi-2.4.0.jar" was rolled back with no failure message
keycloak-1_1       | 22:39:14,593 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYSRV0022: Deploy of deployment "keycloak-server.war" was rolled back with no failure message
keycloak-1_1       | 22:39:14,594 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYMAIL0002: Unbound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
keycloak-1_1       | 22:39:14,595 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0008: Undertow HTTP listener default suspending
keycloak-1_1       | 22:39:14,596 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0007: Undertow HTTP listener default stopped, was bound to 0.0.0.0:8080
keycloak-1_1       | 22:39:14,597 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS]
keycloak-1_1       | 22:39:14,597 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
keycloak-1_1       | 22:39:14,599 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0019: Host default-host stopping
keycloak-1_1       | 22:39:14,600 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0008: Undertow AJP listener ajp suspending
keycloak-1_1       | 22:39:14,601 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0007: Undertow AJP listener ajp stopped, was bound to 0.0.0.0:8009
keycloak-1_1       | 22:39:14,601 INFO  [org.jboss.modcluster] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) MODCLUSTER000002: Initiating mod_cluster shutdown
keycloak-1_1       | 22:39:14,603 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0004: Undertow 2.2.5.Final stopping
keycloak-1_1       | 22:39:14,603 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = h2
keycloak-1_1       | 22:39:17,594 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) 686f5f3e69c1: JOIN(686f5f3e69c1) sent to 910704d8ddf5 timed out (after 3000 ms), on try 7
keycloak-1_1       | 22:39:19,630 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.controller.ParallelBootOperationStepHandler$2@296cb863 for operation parallel-subsystem-boot at address [] failed -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException:     java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.waitForRemovals(OperationContextImpl.java:525)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.handleResult(AbstractOperationContext.java:1559)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:1513)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1496)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.access$400(AbstractOperationContext.java:1360)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeResultHandlerPhase(AbstractOperationContext.java:912)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:762)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:468)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1415)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:529)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:515)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:477)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.server@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:459)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.server@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:412)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:416)
keycloak-1_1       |    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
keycloak-1_1       | 
keycloak-1_1       | 22:39:19,630 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.client] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.controller.ParallelBootOperationStepHandler$2@296cb863 for     operation parallel-subsystem-boot at address [] failed -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
keycloak-1_1       | 22:39:20,953 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) 686f5f3e69c1: JOIN(686f5f3e69c1) sent to 910704d8ddf5 timed out (after 3000 ms), on try 7
keycloak-1_1       | 22:39:24,308 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) 686f5f3e69c1: JOIN(686f5f3e69c1) sent to 910704d8ddf5 timed out (after 3000 ms), on try 7
keycloak-1_1       | 22:39:24,632 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractAddStepHandler$1@7b2fdf4f for     operation add at address [
keycloak-1_1       |     ("socket-binding-group" => "standard-sockets"),
keycloak-1_1       |     ("remote-destination-outbound-socket-binding" => "mail-smtp")
keycloak-1_1       | ] failed -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.waitForRemovals(OperationContextImpl.java:525)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.handleResult(AbstractOperationContext.java:1559)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:1513)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1496)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.access$400(AbstractOperationContext.java:1360)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeResultHandlerPhase(AbstractOperationContext.java:912)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:762)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:468)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1415)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:529)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:515)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:477)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.server@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:459)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.server@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:412)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:416)
keycloak-1_1       |    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
keycloak-1_1       | 
keycloak-1_1       | 22:39:24,633 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.client] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractAddStepHandler$1@7b2fdf4f for operation add at     address [
keycloak-1_1       |     ("socket-binding-group" => "standard-sockets"),
keycloak-1_1       |     ("remote-destination-outbound-socket-binding" => "mail-smtp")
keycloak-1_1       | ] failed -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
keycloak-1_1       | 22:39:29,634 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractAddStepHandler$1@4f909ceb for     operation add at address [
keycloak-1_1       |     ("socket-binding-group" => "standard-sockets"),
keycloak-1_1       |     ("socket-binding" => "txn-status-manager")
keycloak-1_1       | ] failed -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.waitForRemovals(OperationContextImpl.java:525)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.handleResult(AbstractOperationContext.java:1559)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:1513)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1496)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.access$400(AbstractOperationContext.java:1360)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeResultHandlerPhase(AbstractOperationContext.java:912)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:762)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:468)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1415)
keycloak-1_1       |    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:529)
```

Until it gives up:

```
keycloak-1_1       | 22:40:43,851 ERROR [org.jgroups.protocols.JDBC_PING] (Thread-77) JGRP000215: Failed to delete PingData in database
keycloak-1_1       | 22:40:43,859 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0050: Keycloak 15.0.2 (WildFly Core 15.0.1.Final) stopped in 6ms
keycloak-1_1       | base_keycloak-1_1 exited with code 1
```

Any idea what I can do to fix this?  I can't find the volume locally- I'd like to delete that to let it start over.  This is only for localhost debugging.

Comment: Why you don't delete all your DB data with `docker volume rm postgresql_data` and don't start new DB from the scratch?

Comment: I tried that - it tells me "no such volume: postgresql_data".  I'm wondering if that's the actual issue.  I can't find a folder anywhere with the name postgresql_data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have similar issues on my local machine,
what I do then is:

`docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up`
if this does not help then I delete volume, be aware that volume will be named differently that in yaml file, it contains prefix ie:

```
kc-tests_postgresql_data
```

You can check this by using `docker volume ls`
After deleting volume all works fine.
Not best solution but well at least for develop when its destroyed it helps.